# SimpleXML differences with same data on different servers

Tags: php, xml, linux, macos, simplexml

I'm trying to use `xpath` to fetch data from a loaded `SimpleXMLElement`.
Hoever, the same code yields different results on local vs dev servers. Could someone point me in the right direction of what to look for?

Here is the code as ran on both servers:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <ADDDATA>
        <PAGEN>1</PAGEN>
        <DOCN>123456789</DOCN>
        <DATE>06.07.2017</DATE>
    </ADDDATA>
</document>
');

$nodes = $xml->xpath('//DOCN');

var_dump($nodes);
```

Results on local (as expected):

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      public 0 => string '123456789' (length=9)
```

Results on dev (wtf):

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { } }
```

My local env is:

- `OSX10.12.6`
- `homebrew/php/php56: stable 5.6.31 (bottled), HEAD`
- `libxml2: stable 2.9.5 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]`

My server is:

- `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64)`
- `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16 (cli) (built: Apr 20 2016 14:31:27)`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1`

Could the difference in versions be producing the different results?

Is there some global configuration I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `echo $nodes[0]->asXML();` may give some more useful output.  In general `asXML()` gives a better view of the data rather than `var_dump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on `var_dump()` output for inspecting `SimpleXMLElement`s. I think this specific issue you're experiencing is related to [bug #66084](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66084). See in [this demo](https://3v4l.org/j3iJq) that the results change in PHP 5.6.10, which is consistent with what you're experiencing. Bug #66084 was [fixed in PHP 5.6.11](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.11).

You probably already know this, but just in case: `$nodes` contains a list of `SimpleXMLElement`s, not their values. So, to get the value of the node, simply cast each instance as a string, either implicitly or explicitly:

```
echo $nodes[0]; // 123456789 , implicitly
var_dump($nodes[0]->__toString()); // string(9) "123456789", explicitly
var_dump((string)$nodes[0]); // string(9) "123456789", explicitly
```